# Django - Why is the “default value” in view not working?

Tags: django, view, django-templates, django-urls

my index view should query some data with the default "date of the day"value.
For a test, I entered a string as a default value. : "2019-08-01"
My url :

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('<str:date_index>', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

My view:

```
def get_reunions_by_date(date_r):
    return Reunion.objects.filter(datetime_start__startswith=date_r) \
        .order_by('numero', 'hippodrome__nom')

def index(request, date_index="2019-08-01"):
    year, month, day = map(int, date_index.split('-'))
    date_du_jour = date(year, month, day)
  
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
        'reunions': get_reunions_by_date(date_du_jour),
        'date_du_jour': date_du_jour
    })
```

Now, If I enter this url : `myapp/2019-01-01`, it's working, the index template is rendered, but if I enter this url: `myapp/` nothing is rendered.
Why is it not takking the default value `date_index="2019-08-01"` in the view ?
I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should add this to route to your urls:

```
 path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

i mean like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:date_index>', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```